# C++ simple syntax

Tags: c++

I need some help explaining this couple lines of code.. I'm new to c++ and tried looking thru the cplusplus references but still couldn't figure this out..

This function accepts a sequence and a body of text and returns the occurrences of the seq in text... 
I am not sure what size_t .. pos.. or npos do.. thanks a lot..

```
unsigned int countOccurrences(const std::string& seq, const std::string& text){
  size_t count(0);
  size_t pos(0);
  while((pos=text.find(seq, pos))!=std::string::npos) {
    ++pos;
    count++ ;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Comment: `std::string::npos` it is just scope resolution saying `nops` is from `string` scope and the `string` is in `std` scope.  And `size_t count(0);` isn't a syntax error ??

Comment: @SJayesh No, `size_t count(0)` is not a syntax error. It initializes the `size_t count` to the value `0`. Think of what it would mean if instead of `size_t` you had a user-defined type (let's just take vector, for example). `std::vector<int> myVector(0)` is not a syntax error.

Comment: @Justin , yes, got it :). And `size_t` is just returntype userd for sizeof()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npos` indicates the end of the string (you can think of it as being the index version of end ()). `pos` is the position of the search string found in the searched string. It gets incremented in every iteration so that it searches for a new occurrence each time. `size_t` is an unsigned integer type suitable for expressing the sizes of objects in memory.

In this implementation overlapping occurrences get counted, e.g.

Counting  "aaa" in "xaaaay" will count 2 occurrences.